# Treating the word "grammar" in proper grammar

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Driving down the road I saw a state sign that was written poorly. I said, “That’s a bad grammar.’

My wife was offended I said “a” grammar.

I can’t find an answer to see if what I said is acceptable. *Grammar* is a noun.

Comment: Would you say “That’s a poor workmanship”?

Answer (score 5):

That’s not what *a grammar* means. Most commonly, *a grammar* is a book or treatise ***on*** grammar. That’s sense 2 in the OED:

> 2. A treatise or book on grammar.
>
> - **1693**   J. Dryden *Disc. conc. Satire* in J. Dryden et al. tr. Juvenal *Satires* p. li  
>   We have yet no English *Prosodia*, not so much as a tolerable Dictionary, or a Grammar.
> - **1751**   J. Harris *Hermes* ɪ. ix. 179   
>   We are taught in common Grammars that Verbs Active require an Accusative.
> - **1894**   V. Henry (*title*)   
>    A short comparative grammar of English and
>   German.

The original and more general sense of *grammar* they give as:

> 1. a. That department of the study of a language which deals with its inflectional forms or other means of indicating the relations of words in the sentence, and with the rules for employing these in accordance with established usage; usually including also the department which deals with the phonetic system of the language and the principles of its representation in writing. Often preceded by an adjective designating the language referred to, as in *Latin, English, French* grammar.

When speaking of “bad grammar”, this is something else again, and it is never a count noun.

> 3. An individual’s manner of using grammatical forms; speech or writing judged as good or bad according as it conforms to or violates grammatical rules; also speech or writing that is correct according to those rules.
>
> - **1842**   T. B. Macaulay *Frederic the Great* in Ess. (1865) III. 209
>      He had German enough to scold his servants..but his grammar and pronunciation were extremely bad.
> - **1855**   T. B. Macaulay *Hist. Eng*. IV. xviii. 245  
>    The letter may still be read with all the original bad grammar and bad spelling.

And that is why your wife right found your use of ***a** bad grammar* to be . . . **bad grammar**. :)